# how to return all rows even when they have no value in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables: categories and subjects.

Categories table:

```
Name
cat1
cat2
cat3
```

Subjects table:

```
Name    category 
sub1    cat1
sub2    cat1
sub3    cat2
```

What query can I run to get back a result set that contains all the categories and subjects like this:

```
Category  Subject 
cat1      sub1
cat1      sub2
cat2      sub3
cat3      ''
```

Comment: Hint:  `LEFT JOIN`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `outer join`:

```
select c.Name "Category", s.category "Subject"
from Categories c left outer join 
     Subjects s
     on s.category = c.name;
```

Comment: Why the `coalesce`?  In Oracle, an empty string is `NULL`.  That is `'' is null` evaluates to true.

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak. . . It is just intended op.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT category, subject
  FROM categories LEFT JOIN subjects USING (category);
```